# Can i add a codecommit trigger to my lambda function via CloudFormation

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-codecommit

Im writing a lambda function that i want to be triggered by somebody updating the master branch of a repo.  The repo already exists on the account.

Is there a way in cloudformation that i can add the trigger to the lambda function?  I guess at a snip i could cretae some cloudwatch rule to trigger the lambda, but would rather keep it all inside the lambda.

Thanks
R

Comment: Does the Codecommit repo resides in a Cloudformation template? If not, you probably need to use the workaround by cloudwatch rule since it looks like the only way to add codecommit trigger is from AWS::CodeCommit::Repository's "Trigger" Object.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using AWS serverless transform then you can self contain it within the lambda. Although the transform generates the cloudwatch rule and the lambda permission, so it's basically the same you mentioned.

nevertheless here's an example to do what you want

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31


Description: Pipeline which triggers lambda for codecommit changes


Parameters:
  BranchName:
    Default: master
    Description: The GIT branch
    Type: String
  RepositoryName:
    Description: The GIT repository
    Type: String
  StackOwner:
    Description: The stack owner
    Type: String


Resources:

  BasicLambdaRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
          Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Path: "/"
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: root
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: logs:*
                Resource: arn:aws:logs:*:*:*
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: '*'
                Resource: '*'

  PipelineTriggerFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: src/trigger
      Handler: codetrigger.handler
      MemorySize: 256
      Role: !GetAtt BasicLambdaRole.Arn
      Runtime: python3.6
      Timeout: 900
      Environment:
        Variables:
          TestVariable: "TestValue"
      Events:
        CodeCommitPushEvent:
          Type: CloudWatchEvent
          Properties:
            Pattern:
              source:
                - aws.codecommit
              resources:
                - !Sub 'arn:aws:codecommit:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${RepositoryName}'
              detail:
                event:
                  - referenceCreated
                  - referenceUpdated
                repositoryName:
                  - !Ref RepositoryName
                referenceName:
                  - !Ref BranchName
      Tags:
        'owner': !Ref StackOwner
        'task': !Ref RepositoryName
```

Obviously, specify the lambda role better and not give all permissions as provided in the example.